# Stone Cech compactification construction via Special Adjoint Functor Theorem in Riehl

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, compactness

$\newcommand{\chaus}{\textbf{cHaus}}\newcommand{\ctop}{\textbf{Top}}$
Emily Riehl's "Category theory in Context", Section 4.6 "Existence of adjoint functors" uses the "Special Adjoint Functor theorem" on the inclusion functor, which includes the category of compact Hausdorff spaces ($\chaus$) into the category of topological spaces ($\ctop$). This gives us the Stone Cech compactification functor $\beta: \ctop \to \chaus$. I'm trying to understand certain *topological* assertions made. I'll run through the proof as given, and point out topological facts which I don't understand.

##### Proof sketch

We start by seeing that $I \equiv [0, 1]$ is a *coseparating object* for $\chaus$. This means that if $f, g: X \to Y$ such that $f \neq g$,  then there is a function $h: Y \to [0, 1]$ such that $h \circ f \neq h \circ g$. See that $f \neq g$ implies there is an $x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0) \neq g(x_0)$. Now we apply the *Urysohn Lemma*, which states that for Normal (eg. compact Hausdorff) spaces, we can define a continuous function $h: Y \to I$ such that $h(f(x_0)) = 0$ and $h(g(x_0)) = 1$. Since $Y$ is compact Haussdorf and thus normal, we obtain a function $h$ such that $h \circ f \neq h \circ g$.

Next, we consider the set of *all* maps $X \to I$. We take the product of these maps, giving us the map:

$$
X \xrightarrow{\hat \eta} \prod_{\hom(X, I)} I
$$

The claim is that this map is initial amongst the collection of all maps in $X \downarrow \chaus$ --- that is, any other map from $X$ into a compact Hausdorff space $Y$ must factor through $\hat \eta$. **(1: I don't see why this claim is true)**.

Finally, we say because the full product space $\prod_{\hom(X, I)} I$ is compact Haussdorf, a subspace is compact iff it is closed. Why does this imply that the intersection of all subobjects of $\hat \eta: X \to \prod_{\hom(X, I)} I$ is the closure of the image of $\hat \eta$? (**2: I don't see why this claim is true either**).

So I don't understand why this process as described in Riehl constructs the Stone Cech compactification. I'd appreciate clarification of the topological facts I seem to be missing to make this go through.

##### Example 4.6.12

[image]

Comment: The initial object of $X \downarrow \mathbf{cHaus}$ is $\eta$, not $\hat{\eta}$.

Comment: And the claim that $\eta$ is initial involves no topology at all; it is just applying (the proof of) Theorem 4.6.10.